# IPhones that updated to 10.3.1 can no longer choose images to upload to webpage, only snap new ones

Tags: html, ios, file-upload

i honestly don't know alot about IPhones, however i have received a report, and also independently verified, that just before a customer updated his phone, he was able to press the "upload file" button or our webpage, and either choose an existing file, or snap a picture and use that. However immediately after installing the 10.3.1 update, when he presses the exact same button, it goes straight to the camera.

The button looks like this:

```
<input id="inputFilesButton" type="file" name="files[]" capture="camera" accept="application/image, image/*" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; font-size: 15px;" multiple="">
```

So my question is, is there anything i can do, whether it is changing the HTML code, or changing a setting in the IPhone?

**UPDATE:** The same behavior has been duplicated in Safari, Opera and Chrome.

**UPDATE2:** The same behavior has been duplicated on 7 different IPhones, where this problem occured after the update-.

Comment: 10.3.1 introduced [a new file system (APFS)](http://devstreaming.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2016/701q0pnn0ietcautcrv/701/701_introducing_apple_file_system.pdf) which might have something to do with the different file load functionality.

Comment: @freginold this may be a dumb question, but wasn't this done in 10.3, and 10.3.1 came afterwards?

Comment: Nope, you're absolutely right. I misread the article... sorry about that!  There goes that idea.

Comment: Your customer is using Safari on his iPhone, correct? Has he tried your page from any other browser?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed answer. @freginold i will test your theory and get back to you

Comment: @freginold Unfortunately that didn't help. It has now been tested on Safari, Opera and Chrome.

Comment: Weird.  I set that button up as a fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/freginold/gsq5udkL/)... can you test it and see if it gives the same behavior as your site?  If it doesn't, it may be something else in your code.

Comment: Also, has it been tested on any other devices, or just that one iPhone?

Comment: It has been tested on 7 IPhones in total, all had problems after this update.

Comment: Also the fiddle you made, gives the same behaviour. Did it work for you?

Comment: I don't have an iPhone to test it on right now.  Later today I can try to test it on an iPad and see what happens.

Comment: [Here is an updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/freginold/gsq5udkL/1/) with the "capture" attribute removed from the 2nd file input box... Can you see if both boxes give the same result?  The "capture" attribute can make the system prefer camera upload.

Comment: Removing the `capture` element should do it.  I've added it as an answer below.  Let me know if that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the `capture` attribute, the system won't prefer a camera upload, and will ask where your image is coming from (camera, gallery, etc.).

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/freginold/gsq5udkL/1/) with two upload buttons.  The first one has the `capture` attribute set; the second one does not.  The second one should do what you want it to do.  Tested on an iPad running 10.3 -- the first button forced a camera upload but the second button did not.

Removing the `capture` attribute, your button should work:

```
<input id="inputFilesButton" type="file" name="files[]" accept="application/image, image/*" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; font-size: 15px;" multiple="">
```